# overlapping floats: z-index doesn't work

Tags: css

I'm trying to write a horizontal navigation bar with simple drop down menus (again horz). The main menu displays fine. To hide the submenus when not hovering, I did

```
ul#submenu {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10pt;left: 0;
}

ul#mainmenu li:hover ul#submenu li {
    visibility: visible;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}
```

The visibility and appear on hover work fine. However, part of the submenu gets hidden under the float right below. I tried setting `z-index: 0` for that and `z-index: 1` for the submenus, but it still doesn't work. How do I bring it to the top?

Comment: It's rather difficult to imagine the implications of `ul#mainmenu li:hover ul#submenu li` <do stuff>, especially without seeing the accompanying HTML. Could you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demo?

Comment: Or a link to a live page. Whichever is easier.

Comment: @thirtydot: thanks, R.M's suggestion worked. Apparently it was because of `overflow: hidden`, which in fact was a suggestion on S.O. earlier today to a different problem that I had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if `overflow: hidden;` or `overflow: auto` is set in the parent div. That could prevent it from showing up.